# Test for series convergence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am a couple of questions about the infinite series $$f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^n x}{\sqrt{n}}$$ I need to prove that the sequence converges for all $x \in \left( -\frac{1}{2}\pi,  \frac{1}{2}\pi\right)$, prove that the function $f : \left( -\frac{1}{2}\pi,  \frac{1}{2}\pi\right) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and prove that $f: \left( -\frac{1}{2}\pi,  \frac{1}{2}\pi\right) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable. Am I right in thinking that the comparison test will be useful for the first question?

Answer (score 1):

$\left|\frac{\sin^n x}{\sqrt{n}}\right|\leq |\sin x|^n$ and $|\sin x|<1$.

Comment: And to prove that it is continuous, should I use the fact that if a series is uniformly convergent, the sum is a continuous function?

Comment: You can write that $g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is differentiable on $(-1,1)$, and then $f(x)=g(\sin x)$, so $f$ is also differentiable.

Comment: So that would solve the continuity problem in one go as differentiable functions are automatically continuous on the interval.